# Unaccounted for element link in Ruby Integration test

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, tdd

I am running a simple integration test trying to make sure the links I have set up are working properly.  The test keeps returning 1 failure saying that it "expected exactly 2 elements matching 'a[href="/"]'" (which is my root path to my home page) but the test keeps finding 3.  There is only two places where I have referenced the root path via links, and it is in my _header.html.erb and for the life of my I cannot figure out where the 3rd element could be popping up from.

Here is my _header.html.erb code:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Log In" '#' %></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

and my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/new'

  root "static_pages#home"

  get 'help' => "static_pages#help"

  get 'about' => "static_pages#about"

  get 'contact' => "static_pages#contact"

  get 'signup' => "users#new"
end
```

Any help would be appreciated, I a newbie.

Thanks!

Comment: how many vies use the _header partial? not sure if that is relevant. but may be.

Comment: 5, the home page, about, help, contact, and a signup page as of now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the only error, but this line:

```
<li><%= link_to "Log In" '#' %></li>
```

should have a comma between `"Log In"` and `"#"`, like this:

```
<li><%= link_to "Log In", '#' %></li>
```